# reading csv file containing date data in format: dd/mm/yyyy in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to read csv file which contain date data by the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

# Reading the data
import datetime
data = pd.read_csv("E:\Team work\new_cases.csv")
```

Comment: I flagged this question as low quality because you don't actually ask a question and it's not clear what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code with `\\` instead of `\`

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import datetime 

data = pd.read_csv("E:\\Team work\\new_cases.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a peak in the [help centre article on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I rolled your last edit back, since you removed the helpful code-formatting we have here.

Comment: Why won't you leave the snippet there? It's relevant to say where the slashes have to be replaced. The initial answer was great, apart from formatting, why remove relevant info?